# Nice syntax for Validation in another monad

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

I like monad transformers.
For example, I can combine nicely two future optional values like this:

```
val val1:OptionT[Task, Int] = ???
val val2:OptionT[Task, Int] = ???

val sum = for {
  one ← val1
  two ← val2
} yield (one + two)
```

Since `Validation` doesn't have a `Monad[_]` instance, I can't use similar syntax for it. What is the best way, how to sum these two:

```
val val3:Task[ValidationNel[Throwable,Int]] = ???
val val4:Task[ValidationNel[Throwable,Int]] = ???
```

Comment: Your `Task` differs in two examples. One `Task` has no type parameters, but later it seems to have two type parameters.

Comment: no, `Task[_]` takes one type parameter, `OptionT[F[_],A]` takes a type constructor, in the other example, `Task` takes one type param and `ValidationNel` takes two

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for way to accumulate errors or compute result. You may be interested in *macculkin operator*, I mean a pipe at pipe or `|@|` (choose the name you like most) ;)

Example of usage. See how errors are accumulated (*OMG!* and *Holly mum!* are included in result.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val v1: ValidationNel[Throwable, Int] = 1.successNel
val v2: ValidationNel[Throwable, Int] = new RuntimeException("OMG!").failNel
val v3: ValidationNel[Throwable, Int] = new RuntimeException("Holly mom!").failNel

val sum : ValidationNel[Throwable, Int] = (v1 |@| v2 |@| v3 ) (_ + _ + _)
//scala> sum: scalaz.ValidationNel[Throwable,Int] = Failure(NonEmptyList(java.lang.RuntimeException: OMG!, java.lang.RuntimeException: Holly mom!))
```

The often made mistake is when you choose to use for comprehension or map functions. When you decide follow such way you will not able to acumulate errors. Only *OMG!* is accumulated. See below:

```
for( val1 <- v1;
     val2 <- v2;
     val3 <- v3
    ) yield(val1 + val2 + val3)

//res0: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[Throwable],Int] = Failure(NonEmptyList(java.lang.RuntimeException: OMG!))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a semigroup instance for `Int`, you can just add the validations together to get back one `Task[ValidationNel[Throwable,Int]]`:

```
  val sum2 = for {
    three ← val3
    four ← val4
  } yield three +|+ four
```